# list index out of range error for varying length of hash keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a text file. Each line of that file has either 6 fields or 7 fields.

- If there are 7 fields in a line, i am making first 6 fields as a key and 7th field as the value for that key.
- If there are 6 fields in a line, i am making first 5 fields as a key and 6th field as the value for that key.

I don't know if posting the entire code is necessary or not, but for a clear picture, i am posting the entire code.

My code is pasted below:

```
ReqResRS = {}
with contextlib.nested(open(sys.argv[1],'r'), open(sys.argv[2], 'w')) as (inpf, outf):
    lines = [l.split() for l in inpf if l.strip()]
    for l in lines:
            if(l[6]):
                    myKey = (l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3],l[4],l[5])
                    myValue = l[6]
                    if(myKey in ReqResRS):
                            diff = float(l[6])-float(ReqResRS[myKey]);
                            if(float(diff) < 0.000008):
                                    ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
                            else:
                                    ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
                                    outf.write(l[0] + "\t" + l[1] + "\t" + l[2] + "\t" + l[3] + "\t" + l[4] + "\t" + l[5] + "\t" + l[6] + "\n")
                    else:
                            ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
                            outf.write(l[0] + "\t" + l[1] + "\t" + l[2] + "\t" + l[3] + "\t" + l[4] + "\t" + l[5] + "\t" + l[6] + "\n")
            else:
                    myKey = (l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3],l[4])
                    myValue = l[5]
                    if(myKey in ReqResRS):
                            diff = float(l[5])-float(ReqResRS[myKey]);
                            if(float(diff) < 0.000008):
                                    ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
                            else:
                                    ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
                                    outf.write(l[0] + "\t" + l[1] + "\t" + l[2] + "\t" + l[3] + "\t" + l[4] + "\t" + l[5] + "\n")
                    else:
                            ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
                            outf.write(l[0] + "\t" + l[1] + "\t" + l[2] + "\t" + l[3] + "\t" + l[4] + "\t" + l[5] + "\n")
```

Comment: please mention any mistakes in the post so that i can modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(l[6]):
```

fails if your array is to short.
Accessing a value that is not part of the array will allways result in an exception. Therefore you should check beforehand whether the array is long enough, like this:

```
if len(l) == 7:
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you want to change `if l[6]` to `if len(l) == 7`

But this sort of thing should be easier than you're making it (from the code above, you should *need* to special case things based on how many columns your datafile has):

```
myValue = l[-1] 
myKeys = l[:-1]  #tuple(l[:-1]) if you must ...
try:
    diff = float(myValue)-float(ReqResRS[myKey])
    ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
    if(float(diff) >= 0.000008):
        outf.write("\t".join(l) + "\n") 
except KeyError:
    ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
    outf.write("\t".join(l) + "\n")
```

Comment: i think it should be len(l) == 7, not len(l) == 6

Comment: @JustinCarrey -- already fixed, but thanks for helping me keep a good reputation around here :-).

Comment: even better than my proposal!

Answer (score 1):

I guess `if(l[6]):` should be `if(len(l) == 7):` on line 5

Note that you could also write something like

```
try:
    myKey = (l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3], l[4], l[5])
    myValue = l[6]
except IndexError:
    myKey = (l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3], l[4])
    myValue = l[5]

if(myKey in ReqResRS):
    diff = float(myValue) - float(ReqResRS[myKey]);
    if(float(diff) < 0.000008):
            ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
    else:
            ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
            outf.write('{}\t{}\n'.format("\t".join(myKey), myValue)
else:
    ReqResRS[myKey] = myValue
    outf.write('{}\t{}\n'.format("\t".join(myKey), myValue)
```

Comment: i think it should be len(l) == 7, not len(l) == 6

Comment: thanks for noticing. Fixed that and tried to refactor a little bit your code as you've got lots of similarities in your if/else branches (the try/except might not be the best solution here but anyway, you see the idea)